# StringBuilder.delete fails with valid length

Tags: java

I have an webapp running in Tomcat which is throwing an exception but I cannot understand how/why the exception is being thrown as the line of code is seemingly protected by an if statement to check the length and contents.

The exception is:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.delete(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.delete(Unknown Source)
at com.thisco.DoSomething(MyItem.java:785)
```

The code a the line above is:

```
784: if (whereClause.toString().endsWith(" AND "))
785:    whereClause.delete(whereClause.length() - 5, 5);
```

Any ideas how this could happen?
Thanks

Comment: `delete` does not work the way you think: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int)

Comment: Thank you! _<facepalm>_ I have a .Net background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StringBuilder.delete` method takes in two parameters, a `start` and `end` index. In your case, if the length of the StringBuilder is greater than 10, your start index will be larger than your end index (for example, if length = 20, start = 15 and end = 5), which will throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I think that what you want to do is remove the string from the end, in which case you should replace line 785 with `whereClause.delete(whereClause.length() - 5, whereClause.length());`.